# Shifting an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have written a SortedIntList class that has an add and get method.

I am calling the following four methods:

```
SortedIntList mySortedIntList = new SortedIntList();
mySortedIntList.add(9);
mySortedIntList.add(7);
System.out.println("0 is :"+mySortedIntList.get(0));
System.out.println("1 is :"+mySortedIntList.get(1));
```

My get  and add methods looks like this:

```
public void add(Integer newValue) {
    int position = 0;
    while(position < list.size()){
        int currentPosValue = list.get(position);
        if(newValue <= currentPosValue){
            for(int i=list.size()-1; i>=position; i--){
                int toBeShifted = list.get(i);
                list.set(i+1, toBeShifted);
            }
            list.set(position, newValue);
            return;
        }
        position++;
    }
    list.add(newValue);
}


       public int get(int i) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    // Postcondition: If i < 0 or i >= size() throws 
    // IndexOutOfBoundsException, otherwise returns the value 
    // at position i of this IntList
    if (i < 0 || i >= list.size()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("SortedIntList.get");
    } else {
        return ((Integer) list.get(i)).intValue();
    }
}





    public int get(int i) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        // Postcondition: If i < 0 or i >= size() throws 
        // IndexOutOfBoundsException, otherwise returns the value 
        // at position i of this IntList
        if (i < 0 || i >= list.size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("SortedIntList.get");
        } else {
            return ((Integer) list.get(i)).intValue();
        }
    }
```

I have written it out on paper, and it seems logical, but the code blows up on:

`System.out.println("1 is :"+mySortedIntList.get(1))` line, apparently 1 is outofbounds, but I don't see how.

Comment: apparently I added code tags incorrectly, how can I fix that?

Comment: You'll want to look at the FAQ as you don't use [code][/code] tags for this forum. Rather, you press the {} code button and it indents your code 4 spaces.

Comment: you posted the `add` method not the `get`.

Comment: What is list? Is it an ArrayList? Could you post the initialization code?

Comment: I would strongly recommend running your code with a debugger, so you can see what's going on inside your list, at every point in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the Java Doc helps. Apparently using set() requires there to already be a value at the position you are trying to override. I needed to use add(position, value) instead :-)

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use the [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29), this standard Java method will sort your Collection for you. This way you don't have to deal with the sorting yourself, good luck!

Comment: I would do that, but its a data structures course, so I'm not allowed to :-(

Comment: You could add the "homework" tag so everyone knows not to solve the problem completely for you.

Comment: Why don't you ask your course' instructor then? That's where you pay for, right? Good luck!

Comment: I plan to, but I'm just trying to understand it for myself, and after writing out the variable values, and going over the code on paper, it seemed to work, but I can't get it to for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems.

First, `list.set(i+i, toBeShifted);` should probably be `list.set(i+1, toBeShifted);`.  When you are adding 7 to the list, your list size is 1.  In the for loop, you initialize i to be 0 (list size - 1).  When you call list.set(i+i, toBeShifted) you are calling list.set(0, toBeShifted), and so not actually shifting the value.

Second, though you don't run into it with adding a 9 and then a 7, you will end up in an infinite while loop.  You never change the value of position.  If you add a 9 and then a larger number, you're hosed.

Comment: You're right, I meant to have i+1, not i+i, and I corrected the infinite loop (possible) issue. I'm still not seeing what my problem is, even after fixing that, I still get the same error.

Comment: I may have stumbled onto something. I wrote a test:                            ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
       a.add(1);
       a.set(1,0);  This throws a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1 how can that be?

Comment: List.set "Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the specified element".  You have nothing in position 1 when you are trying to set the 7, and so nothing to replace.  This is the cause of the crash.  Before you go into the for loop, you need to add a new item to the list (which will add it to the end of the list).  And then when you do the shift, there is a place for the numbers to go.  You will also need to change your for loop to `for(int i=list.size()-2; i>=position; i--){` because the size of the list increases by one before this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use list's `set()` to add to a list: for example, if you try to set something at index 1 to something in a list of size 1, you'll get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Basically, you need to `add` first.